# App crash on some android device with errors (Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode

Tags: android, reactjs, webpack, webview, babeljs

I am running a react app in android webview where i am getting this error in Android Api Level 23 and below. Is there any webpack or babel setting to resolve this?

Comment: try to update your nodejs version

Comment: @UsamaAltaf I have latest Node version. But when I am trying to use that in old Android Version Like Android 6 Api23, i am getting these error. I am using babel-loader too but still getting these.